# Getting names from blameble behaviour extension in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

By using the [Blameble Behaviour](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/blameable-behavior/) extension in the Yii Framework, I wanted to track the creator and updater. Here I am able to record their ids, and now I want to know how to get their names from that.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to add a a relation in the model

```
'creator' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'my_own_creator_column_name'),
'updater' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'my_own_updater_column_name'),
```

and then you can get the name/email of the user from `$model->creator` and `$model->updater`

Comment: it is showing the the id in `CDetailView`.I want to get the username in `CDetailView`.

Comment: for that you have to specify the attribute `'creator.name'` in `CDetailView`